# Llamar al constructor por defecto de una clase en otra clase

Tags: java

Hol soy nuevo en Java,

Tengo el siguiente constructor por defecto en la clase `Product`:

```
public Product() throws ProductException {
        this("Lorem Ipsum", 2011, "lorem ipsum description", 7.50);
    }
```

Después tengo otra clase llamada, `Physical Product`. En esta quiero llamar al constructor por defecto de la clase Product() pero no sé como hacerlo. He hecho lo siguiente:

```
public PhysicalProduct(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price) throws ProductException{
        this("Lorem Ipsum", 2011, "lorem ipsum description", 7.50);
    }
```

Sin embargo, me marca un error de `"Recursive constructor invocation"`. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Como comentario, mencionar que la clase `PhysicalProduct` es una clase que hereda de `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para llamar al constructor de la clase padre desde una clase derivada se utiliza la llamada a la función `super()`. La función `this()` se utiliza para llamar a otro constructor dentro de la misma clase.

En tu ejemplo, la función `this()` dentro del constructor de la case `PhysicalProduct` está llamandose a sí mismo, por eso devuelve el error de llamada recursiva al constructor. Debes sustituirlo por una llamada a la función `super()`.

```java
public PhysicalProduct(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price) throws ProductException{
    super("Lorem Ipsum", 2011, "lorem ipsum description", 7.50);
}
```

Comment: Te llevas mi +1 sería de mayor utilidad si pusieras el código del OP usando el método que usas. Así quedaría más claro y podría ser de mejor ayuda para otros que pasen por esta pregunta.